# Ошибка при запуске программы на си используя gtk и glade

Tags: c, gui, gtk, glade

Ошибка

> gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed.

Код на Си:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

G_MODULE_EXPORT void helloworld (GtkButton *button, gpointer label) {
    gtk_label_set_text (label, "Привет");
}

static GtkWidget*
create_window (void){

    GtkWidget *app;
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GError *error = NULL;

    builder = gtk_builder_new ();

    if (!gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "Glade_1.ui", &error)){
        g_critical ("Не могу загрузить файл: %s", error->message);
        g_error_free (error);
    }

    gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);
    app = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));

    if(!app){
        g_critical ("Ошибка при получении виджета окна");
    }

    g_object_unref (builder);
    return app;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = create_window ();
    gtk_widget_show (window);
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Содержание **Glade_1.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkBox" id="window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="margin_left">10</property>
    <property name="margin_right">10</property>
    <property name="margin_top">10</property>
    <property name="margin_bottom">10</property>
    <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLabel" id="label">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Метка</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">True</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="position">0</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="button">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Кнопка</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
        <signal name="clicked" handler="helloworld" object="label" swapped="no"/>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">False</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="position">1</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Компилирую в sublime text 3 с помощью:

```
"gcc -g -o ${file_base_name} $file_name `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs` -Wall -Wextra -rdynamic"
```

Нашел много вопросов с аналогичной ошибкой. В основном проблема в том, что при вызове функции `gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window")` не соответствует имя объекта в **xml** файле и имя указанное в аргументе функции. В моем случае все вроде бы соответствует, но программа не запускается и выдает эту ошибку.
ОС Ubuntu 18.04.3.
Пример взят из статьи на хабре и немного адаптирован под мой случай (изначально ошибок было больше).[Ссылка на статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/136922/)

Очень хотелось бы понять что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ. 
Как я понял, проблема заключалась в том, что необходимо поверх `GtkWindow` накладывать все объекты, в данном случае это `GtkBox`, внутри которого `label` и `button`. 
В моем **xml** файле `GtkWindow`, к сожалению, отсутствует, и после того как я переформировал его добавив первым слоем этот самый `GtkWindow`, ошибка пропала.
Вот корректный вариант **xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <property name="gravity">north</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="margin_left">10</property>
        <property name="margin_right">10</property>
        <property name="margin_top">10</property>
        <property name="margin_bottom">10</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Метка</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Кнопка</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="helloworld" object="label" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```